# Keycloak - spring boot - external login web page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, model-view-controller, keycloak

I want to integrate spring boot security with keycloak. But the thing is, I do not want to use keycloak login page, I want to use my own custom login web page from my mvc project and integrate it with keycloak.

Can you guys suggest some documentation or provide some help on the matter please?

Answer (score 0):

You have to deploy a custom theme to your keycloak server to be able to modify templates. You can find more information in the [Keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#deploying-themes)

Comment: is there no way to integrate keycloak with the current scenario ? like get password from textbox etc ?

Comment: The whole idea is that the login procedure will take place 'in' keycloak. So, when you encounter a page where you need to be logged in, it should redirect you to the keycloak login page with a return url. When you're logged in, it redirects you back to the return url (your application).

Comment: I run into the same problem, soooo it actually cant be done..

Comment: @lifeTech did you find any solutions for this approach ?

Comment: @thahgr I'm not sure it can't be done (you'll probably end up with a custom OAuth2 implementation instead of letting Keycloak handle this for you) but the recommended way is to use a custom theme for the realm you want to change the login page for. Shouldn't be too hard!